# JMockit initialization issue on MAC OS X El Capitan

Tags: java, jmockit

I am on MAC OS X Version 10.11.6 & using JVM OpenJDK-1.7.0_79

When trying to use JMockit, I keep getting the below message when running the specific test :-
java.lang.IllegalStateException: To run on Dynamic Code Evolution 64-Bit Server VM use -javaagent:/jmockit-1.38.jar

And eventually the test fails with below error :-

```
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JMockit didn't get initialized; please check jmockit.jar precedes junit.jar in the classpath
    at mockit.internal.startup.Startup.verifyInitialization(Startup.java:124)
    at mockit.MockUp.<clinit>(MockUp.java:59)
    ... 31 more
```

I have already made sure about the jar ordering and also I have the same setup on another machine (the only thing different is MAC OS X version is 10.10.5)
and there I am able to run the tests successfully (without having to add -javaagent)

Moreover running with the suggested -javaagent crashes the JVM with some memory dump.